# What does "nib" and "xib" stand for?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I wonder why that file extension is called `nib` or `xib`.

I guess that the *ib* in *nib* is `Interface Builder`.

But the `n`? Or the `x`? Any idea?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`nib` stands for "NeXT Interface Builder", whereas `xib` is for "Mac OS X Interface Builder".

Comment: I had assumed the X was for XML.  I guess it works both ways!

Comment: Is this answer correct? It's different from other answers.

Comment: Yea I am sure XIB stands for Xml Interface Builder and NeXT is short for NextStep and thats what NS is short for in objective c

Answer (score 11):

I think the "n" would mean NextStep, the "x" was added to indicate the new XML based format.

Answer (score 4):

- "nib" stands for **Next Interface Builder**
- "xib"  stands for **Xml Interface Builder**.

Answer (score 3):

(N in "NextStep" Or X in "XML") + Interface Builder